# Rendering an array in component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Looking for an advice or best practices on this. Am I doing it right?

My Reducer:

```
export default function(){
    return [
      {
        id: '01',
        name: 'Cersei Lannister',
        city: 'Kings Landings'
      },
      {
        id: '02',
        name: 'Margaery Tyrell',
        city: 'Hign Garden'
      },
      {
        id: '03',
        name: 'Daenerys Targaryen',
        city: 'Dragon Stone'
      },
      {
        id: '04',
        name: 'Ygritte',
        city: 'Free Folk'
      },
      {
        id: '05',
        name: 'Arya Stark',
        city: 'Winter Fell'
      }
    ]
}
```

I've combined this reducer in `allReducers` as `gotPeople`. I am using this in a component `myApp`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MyApp extends Component {

    render(){

        const renData = this.props.gotPeople.map((data, idx) => {
            return (
                <View key={idx}>
                  <Text>{data.id}</Text>
                  <Text>{data.name} of {data.city}</Text>
                </View> 
            )
        });

        return(
            <View>
                {renData}
            </View> 
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    gotPeople: state.gotPeople
  }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps )( MyApp )
```

And when I `import MyApp from ./MyApp;` in my `index.android.js` and call it in the `View` like `<MyApp />` it works. Everything is displayed properly. I'm not sure if this is a proper way to do it? Is there any better way?

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reducer is not actually look "reducerish", i.e. it does not reduce anything. But let's assume it's just a placeholder used for the purpose of example. In this case everything look ok, though I would rewrite your component a bit to make it shorter:

```js
const MyApp = ({ gotPeople }) => (
  <View>
    {gotPeople.map((data, idx) => (
       <View key={idx}>
         <Text>{data.id}</Text>
         <Text>{data.name} of {data.city}</Text>
       </View> 
    )}
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Apart from the length of the component, there is no mistake, right? I mean I'm calling the data in the array with `{renData}` properly right?